# Use Visual Composer in Storefront Single Product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, visual-composer, storefront

I'm trying to figure out how to display my visual composer elements inside of my Storefront single product page.

I can view visual composer in the backend, but it is not appearing in my single product post.

Is there a particular hook that I need to call for it to show?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your WordPress dashboard. Goto "Visual Composer > Role Manager". In Post types field, select "custom". And check the "post" checkbox button.

Comment: I had already done with with the "product" checkbox button (and now with the "post" as well). I see VC in the backend, but when I go to post nothing shows.